# How does facebook achieve write scalability?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, memcached, scalability

I studied a paper on memcached published by facebook. There I found that they have one Master Region and all other geographic regions are slaves.

1. I want to know how does facebook handle the master region in terms of write scalability, in the midst of such a high load?
2. Why does it have only one master region?
3. What are other options than manual sharding to achieve write scalability?

Comment: what I am interested in knowing is how the Master region is handled? as in how many replicas do they maintain! Obviously, they can not have a single server acting as Master...they must be having a cluster of master servers and some way of dividing the write requests.

Comment: I just came across that People share more than 4.75 billion things every day on Facebook like status updates, wall posts, photos, videos and comments, Facebook says. They also "Like" more than 4.5 billion things daily and send more than 10 billion messages.

Answer (score 2):

Ex Head of Facebook's Seattle Office Ari Steinberg came to my University of Washington Database class to talk about how Facebook scales their servers.

From what I remember, Facebook has all write requests go to the master server, and then that information is propagated to servers in other regions. This works because the number of write requests is a lot smaller than the number of read requests, so one group of servers is able to handle all the write requests. (Think about typical Facebook usage...read posts, read posts, maybe leave a comment or message once in a while).

This means that if you do a read request and your request is sent to a group of servers that is not the master group, there is a chance you are viewing old posts. If someone posted a new status and the master server had not forwarded the post to the server you are reading from, it will not know about this write yet and give you old data. Facebook values quick page loads over the most accurate data, so they use this design. Most users will never realize they are viewing old information, because they do not know the new posts exists.

Note: I believe they mentioned they have a special case for when you are trying to read your own writes. If you update your profile picture, and then refresh the page, they will make sure your request is sent to the master server so you get the most updated information. It is bad user experience if you update your profile picture and then see your old picture when you refresh the page. However, if someone else goes to view your profile, it does not matter what picture is shown because the user does not know that you have updated it.

Comment: likes should be generating some decent amount of write requests, all matters is how they are stored

Comment: I don't think the storeage space is the issue. Each data center has all the information stored in it. The problem is the number of requests/second each data center can process, and minimizing the time it takes for a request to be returned.

Even with likes, the number of reads is still >>> the number of likes. However it is also possible they handle likes and other similar stuff differently because they are less important to be accurate.

Comment: I also remember Ari mentioning the like count is actually very inaccurate for posts with a large number of likes. No not remember why this is. Possibly because the accuracy of like count is not very important, so they do not spend a lot of resources worrying about its accuracy.

Comment: what I am interested in knowing is how the Master region is handled? as in how many replicas do they maintain! Obviously, they can not have a single server acting as Master...they must be having a cluster of master servers and some way of dividing the write requests.

Comment: To answer this question you should research sharding a database. The basic idea is they will hash on some unique identifier of the request and use that to determine which server to send the request to. I believe in Facebook's early days, they used your school to determine which server the request gets sent to (All Harvard requests to one server, all Duke requests to another and so on). Today they probably use account ID or something similar to sort the requests.

Comment: is it wise to use some auto sharding technique like NDB cluster?